# How to update outputText by onchange selectList in VF

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

I newbie in SF, and i cant figure it out how to change my output text, when choose some option in select list. I`ve taken an error "Invalid bind expression type of Car__c for column of type String".

```
        <apex:pageBlockSection id="cars" collapsible="false">
            <apex:selectList id="chooseCar" value="{! CarList }" size="1">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{! carSelectOptionList }" />
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="car_ours" action="{! passCarToController }"/>
            </apex:selectList> 
        </apex:pageBlockSection>  
        
        <apex:pageBlockSection id="car_ours" collapsible="false">
                <apex:outputText value="{! start_ours }">Working Hours Start:</apex:outputText>
                <apex:outputText value="{! end_ours }">Working Hours End:</apex:outputText>                                          
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Controller:

```
public with sharing class AppointmentsPageController {
public List<Car__c> CarList {get;set;}
public List<SelectOption> carSelectOptionList {get;set;}
public Time start_ours {get;set;}
public Time end_ours {get;set;}

public AppointmentsPageController (){ 
    carSelectOptionList = new List<SelectOption>();
    
    carList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Car__c];
    for (car__c cr : carList){ 
        carSelectOptionList.add(new SelectOption(cr.Id, cr.Name)); 
    }

public void passCarToController() {
    start_ours = [Select Working_Hours_Start__c From Car__c Where Name = :CarList Limit 1].Working_Hours_Start__c;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [selectList documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_selectList.htm) states:

> If multiselect is true, the **value** attribute must be of type String[] or a List of strings. Otherwise, it must be of type String.

That's why you're getting the error: *Invalid bind expression type of Car__c for column of type String*.

Your selectList hasn't `multiselect="true"`, so the value attribute must point to a String variable and since you're using the `Id` of `Car__c` records as value of the SelectOption, the WHERE condition of the query is currently wrong.
Keep in mind that the first parameter of SelectOption constructor is the value returned to the controller.
[SelectOption(value, label)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_System_SelectOption_ctor_2.htm)

> value
> Type: String
> The string that is returned to the Visualforce controller if the option is selected by a user.

**Controller**:

```
public with sharing class AppointmentsPageController {
    public String carId {get;set;} // The variable referred by the selectList  
    public List<SelectOption> carSelectOptionList {get;set;}
    public Time start_ours {get;set;}
    public Time end_ours {get;set;}

    public AppointmentsPageController (){ 
        carSelectOptionList = new List<SelectOption>();
        for (car__c cr : [SELECT Id, Name FROM Car__c]) { // A where condition or a limit might be useful
            carSelectOptionList.add(new SelectOption(cr.Id, cr.Name)); 
        }

    public void passCarToController() {
        // Add the field for 'end_ours' to the query
        Car__c car = [SELECT Working_Hours_Start__c FROM Car__c WHERE Id = :carId Limit 1];
        start_ours = car.Working_Hours_Start__c;
        // end_ours = car.Working_Hours_End__c;
    }
}
```

**Page**:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection id="cars" collapsible="false">
    <apex:selectList id="chooseCar" value="{! carId }" size="1">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{! carSelectOptionList }" />
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="car_ours" action="{! passCarToController }"/>
    </apex:selectList> 
</apex:pageBlockSection>  

<apex:pageBlockSection id="car_ours" collapsible="false">
        <apex:outputText value="{! start_ours }">Working Hours Start:</apex:outputText>
        <apex:outputText value="{! end_ours }">Working Hours End:</apex:outputText>                                          
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't read the documentation carefully, thanks for sharing.